# Why use @class in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop

Why would we use the `@class` forward declaration in this code? What would happen if we comment out the `@class PAWLoginViewController;`? Thanks!

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class PAWLoginViewController;

@protocol PAWLoginViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)loginViewControllerDidLogin:(PAWLoginViewController *)controller;

@end
```

Comment: downvoted, because you could've just commented it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simple way, If you comment out the `@class` then it will show the error as `unknown type name`. Because you are passing the class reference in the parameter. But you have not declared class name.

Answer (score 2):

It's a *forward declaration* and lets the compiler know that the class exists without it having to see the full class declaration.  It's designed to save compilation time.

**EDIT** Thanks to @nielsbot for reminding me that it's also good for avoiding circular dependencies when importing header files (i.e. `A.h` imports `B.h` which imports `A.h`).

If you actually want to use the class (like access members or derive from it), then the compiler will need to see the class declaration, which is normally accomplished using an `#import` pre-processor statement.

Comment: I think it's more to save you from having to import entire header files and avoid header file interdependencies than it is to save compilation time, although it may have that effect.

Comment: @nielsbot What would be the benefit of avoiding the reading of lots of header files if not to save compilation time?  However you are right, that it also avoids circular dependencies.

Comment: Avoiding header file interdependencies, as I stated

Comment: Circular dependencies is what you meant though.

Comment: Perhaps in most cases, yes.